# Formato de data errado

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

Estou com um problema e não tenho ideia de como resolver, se trata do seguinte: A data em um sistema que estou modificando não mostra na `View` corretamente.

Está desta forma:

```
0404/0606/2018181818 9:56:19 AM
```

Onde deveria mostrar:

```
04/06/2018 9:56:19 AM
```

Já notei que o codeigniter tem um helper que formata datas, porém não consigo identificar o erro e nem sei se o erro vem dali, pois não consegui identificar onde está o "construtor" das datas no código que está sendo estudado (acho que nem vem ao caso, caso venha eu posto o trecho), porém como todas as datas são mostradas da mesma maneira, imagino que deva estar partindo de algum ponto em comum.

imagem de exemplo (assim que está no momento, em todos os locais do sistema):

[image: Data errada.]

Alguma idéia?

Comment: poste seu código. Mas possivelmente você só precisaria colocar algo tipo `d-m-yy` e está usando `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: Seu comentário foi bem esclarecedor. De fato o formato está sendo gerenciado pela própria aplicação em um menu próprio, alterei as configurações para o que foi sugerido e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado :D

Comment: ainda sugiro você colocar a parte do código que estava incorreta na pergunta; se for o caso, adicione também uma resposta com a solução para ser marcada como correta para que a pergunta não fique em aberto.

Comment: na pergunta acredito que não tenho como por causa da reputação :s mas vou adicionar uma resposta com a solução.

Comment: pode sim, você edita sua própria pergunta. Mas se não conseguir, coloca erro e solução na resposta ;)

Comment: acabou que não consegui, to pegando o jeito ainda xD já publiquei a solução, muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: blz. Depois marca ela como correta e tá tudo certo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolvido

Como notado nos comentários o problema não estava em linhas de código em si. Vendo o `date_helper.php` e levando em consideração o que foi sugerido nos comentários da pergunta, vi que o sistema já estava todo preparado para tratamento de data e hora em todos os formatos e de uma forma bem sistemática.

Acabou que o sistema tem uma seção de configurações onde fica setado o formado de data e hora, onde apliquei o que foi sugerido e funcionou perfeitamente.

### Erro:

[image: Erro]

### Solução:

[image: Solução]